# How do I pass dynamic values to Django urls to avoid NoReverseMatch at error

Tags: django, variables, url

I am trying to build a hotel reservation app with Django, but I am having trouble passing the data through the app.

I continue to get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /search_results/
Reverse for 'more_info_page' with keyword arguments '{'room_type': 'double', 'check_in_date': '2023-12-07', 'checkout_date': '2023-12-09', 'guests': '1'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['more_info_page/(?P<room_type>[^/]+)/(?P<check_in_date>[^/]+)/(?P<check_out_date>[^/]+)/(?P<guests>[^/]+)/\\Z']
```

I cannot understand how I should pass these to the URL.

Here is the HTML line causing the problems

```
    <a href="{% url 'more_info_page' room_type=room_type check_in_date=checkin_date checkout_date=checkout_date guests=guests %}" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
```

Here is my search_results view

```
    def search_results(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
      checkin_date = request.POST.get('checkinDate')
      checkout_date = request.POST.get('checkoutDate')
      guests = request.POST.get('guests')

      check_in_date = datetime.strptime(checkin_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
      check_out_date = datetime.strptime(checkout_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

      available_rooms = Room.objects.filter(available=True)
      booked_rooms = Reservation.objects.filter(
          check_in_date__lte=check_out_date,
          check_out_date__gt=check_in_date
      ).values_list('room_id', flat=True)
      available_rooms = available_rooms.exclude(id__in=booked_rooms)

      available_room_types = available_rooms.values_list('type', flat=True).distinct()

      context = {
          'checkin_date': checkin_date,
          'checkout_date': checkout_date,
          'guests': guests,
          'available_room_types': available_room_types,
      }
      
      return render(request, 'results.html', context)
  else:
      return HttpResponse("Method not allowed")
```

Here is my URL pattern

```
    path('more_info_page/<str:room_type>/<str:check_in_date>/<str:check_out_date>/<str:guests>/', views.more_info_page, name='more_info_page'),
```

I have tried various permutations of passing the context, but I continue to get this reverse error.

Comment: Do you have some path like `path("search_results/", ...)` in your urls.py ? Also you didn't shared `views.more_info_page` from your `path("more_info_page/"...)`

Answer (score 0):

`checkout_date` in your `{% url %}` tag is different than `check_out_date` in your URL `path()`.

Captured URL parameters get passed like other Python keyword arguments to the view. If you're using syntax of `{% url a1=a1, b1=b1 %}`, the keys have to match the parameter names given in `path()`.

Aside: with that many parameters, `{% url %}` tags get difficult to maintain over time. For instance, renaming a `path()` parameter could imply large find+replace operations to update every template that referenced it by keyword in a `{% url %}` tag. In your case, the parameters you're capturing in the URL don't have any real hierarchy since they're mixed + matched search terms. Unless you have a specific reason to use `POST` for this form, URL query strings using HTTP `GET` for your search terms (e.g., `?room_type=double`) may be easier to manage.